# Reactable not working in production mode but working fine in development mode

Tags: reactjs

After building an app based on Reactable https://github.com/glittershark/reactable suddenly reactable doesnt render anything when in production mode. It goes blank. While the dev mode works completly fine.

I dont even know what to check.

Im using CRA.

This is how it looks in my production build

```
<table class="table" itesperpage="8"><tbody class="reactable-data"></tbody></table>
```

And nothing else

Meanwhile the dev build has:

```
<table class="table" itesperpage="8"><thead><tr class="reactable-filterer"><td colspan="2"><input type="text" class="reactable-filter-input" value=""></td></tr><tr class="reactable-column-header"><th class="reactable-th-email reactable-header-sortable " role="button" tabindex="0">Email</th><th class="reactable-th-manage reactable-header-sortable " role="button" tabindex="0">Manage</th></tr></thead><tbody class="reactable-data"><tr><td label="Email">test@test.com</td><td label="Manage"><div><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="edit" class="svg-inline--fa fa-edit fa-w-18 editIcon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M402.3 344.9l32-32c5-5 13.7-1.5 13.7 5.7V464c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48H48c-26.5 0-48-21.5-48-48V112c0-26.5 21.5-48 48-48h273.5c7.1 0 10.7 8.6 5.7 13.7l-32 32c-1.5 1.5-3.5 2.3-5.7 2.3H48v352h352V350.5c0-2.1.8-4.1 2.3-5.6zm156.6-201.8L296.3 405.7l-90.4 10c-26.2 2.9-48.5-19.2-45.6-45.6l10-90.4L432.9 17.1c22.9-22.9 59.9-22.9 82.7 0l43.2 43.2c22.9 22.9 22.9 60 .1 82.8zM460.1 174L402 115.9 216.2 301.8l-7.3 65.3 65.3-7.3L460.1 174zm64.8-79.7l-43.2-43.2c-4.1-4.1-10.8-4.1-14.8 0L436 82l58.1 58.1 30.9-30.9c4-4.2 4-10.8-.1-14.9z"></path></svg><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="trash-alt" class="svg-inline--fa fa-trash-alt fa-w-14 editIcon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M268 416h24a12 12 0 0 0 12-12V188a12 12 0 0 0-12-12h-24a12 12 0 0 0-12 12v216a12 12 0 0 0 12 12zM432 80h-82.41l-34-56.7A48 48 0 0 0 274.41 0H173.59a48 48 0 0 0-41.16 23.3L98.41 80H16A16 16 0 0 0 0 96v16a16 16 0 0 0 16 16h16v336a48 48 0 0 0 48 48h288a48 48 0 0 0 48-48V128h16a16 16 0 0 0 16-16V96a16 16 0 0 0-16-16zM171.84 50.91A6 6 0 0 1 177 48h94a6 6 0 0 1 5.15 2.91L293.61 80H154.39zM368 464H80V128h288zm-212-48h24a12 12 0 0 0 12-12V188a12 12 0 0 0-12-12h-24a12 12 0 0 0-12 12v216a12 12 0 0 0 12 12z"></path></svg></div></td></tr><tr><td label="Email">paco@paco.com</td><td label="Manage"><div><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="edit" class="svg-inline--fa fa-edit fa-w-18 editIcon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M402.3 344.9l32-32c5-5 13.7-1.5 13.7 5.7V464c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48H48c-26.5 0-48-21.5-48-48V112c0-26.5 21.5-48 48-48h273.5c7.1 0 10.7 8.6 5.7 13.7l-32 32c-1.5 1.5-3.5 2.3-5.7 2.3H48v352h352V350.5c0-2.1.8-4.1 2.3-5.6zm156.6-201.8L296.3 405.7l-90.4 10c-26.2 2.9-48.5-19.2-45.6-45.6l10-90.4L432.9 17.1c22.9-22.9 59.9-22.9 82.7 0l43.2 43.2c22.9 22.9 22.9 60 .1 82.8zM460.1 174L402 115.9 216.2 301.8l-7.3 65.3 65.3-7.3L460.1 174zm64.8-79.7l-43.2-43.2c-4.1-4.1-10.8-4.1-14.8 0L436 82l58.1 58.1 30.9-30.9c4-4.2 4-10.8-.1-14.9z"></path></svg><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="trash-alt" class="svg-inline--fa fa-trash-alt fa-w-14 editIcon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M268 416h24a12 12 0 0 0 12-12V188a12 12 0 0 0-12-12h-24a12 12 0 0 0-12 12v216a12 12 0 0 0 12 12zM432 80h-82.41l-34-56.7A48 48 0 0 0 274.41 0H173.59a48 48 0 0 0-41.16 23.3L98.41 80H16A16 16 0 0 0 0 96v16a16 16 0 0 0 16 16h16v336a48 48 0 0 0 48 48h288a48 48 0 0 0 48-48V128h16a16 16 0 0 0 16-16V96a16 16 0 0 0-16-16zM171.84 50.91A6 6 0 0 1 177 48h94a6 6 0 0 1 5.15 2.91L293.61 80H154.39zM368 464H80V128h288zm-212-48h24a12 12 0 0 0 12-12V188a12 12 0 0 0-12-12h-24a12 12 0 0 0-12 12v216a12 12 0 0 0 12 12z"></path></svg></div></td></tr><tr><td label="Email">bi@bi.com</td><td label="Manage"><div><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="edit" class="svg-inline--fa fa-edit fa-w-18 editIcon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M402.3 344.9l32-32c5-5 13.7-1.5 13.7 5.7V464c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48H48c-26.5 0-48-21.5-48-48V112c0-26.5 21.5-48 48-48h273.5c7.1 0 10.7 8.6 5.7 13.7l-32 32c-1.5 1.5-3.5 2.3-5.7 2.3H48v352h352V350.5c0-2.1.8-4.1 2.3-5.6zm156.6-201.8L296.3 405.7l-90.4 10c-26.2 2.9-48.5-19.2-45.6-45.6l10-90.4L432.9 17.1c22.9-22.9 59.9-22.9 82.7 0l43.2 43.2c22.9 22.9 22.9 60 .1 82.8zM460.1 174L402 115.9 216.2 301.8l-7.3 65.3 65.3-7.3L460.1 174zm64.8-79.7l-43.2-43.2c-4.1-4.1-10.8-4.1-14.8 0L436 82l58.1 58.1 30.9-30.9c4-4.2 4-10.8-.1-14.9z"></path></svg><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="trash-alt" class="svg-inline--fa fa-trash-alt fa-w-14 editIcon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M268 416h24a12 12 0 0 0 12-12V188a12 12 0 0 0-12-12h-24a12 12 0 0 0-12 12v216a12 12 0 0 0 12 12zM432 80h-82.41l-34-56.7A48 48 0 0 0 274.41 0H173.59a48 48 0 0 0-41.16 23.3L98.41 80H16A16 16 0 0 0 0 96v16a16 16 0 0 0 16 16h16v336a48 48 0 0 0 48 48h288a48 48 0 0 0 48-48V128h16a16 16 0 0 0 16-16V96a16 16 0 0 0-16-16zM171.84 50.91A6 6 0 0 1 177 48h94a6 6 0 0 1 5.15 2.91L293.61 80H154.39zM368 464H80V128h288zm-212-48h24a12 12 0 0 0 12-12V188a12 12 0 0 0-12-12h-24a12 12 0 0 0-12 12v216a12 12 0 0 0 12 12z"></path></svg></div></td></tr><tr><td label="Email">roman_pastu@yahoo.es</td><td label="Manage"><div><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="edit" class="svg-inline--fa fa-edit fa-w-18 editIcon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M402.3 344.9l32-32c5-5 13.7-1.5 13.7 5.7V464c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48H48c-26.5 0-48-21.5-48-48V112c0-26.5 21.5-48 48-48h273.5c7.1 0 10.7 8.6 5.7 13.7l-32 32c-1.5 1.5-3.5 2.3-5.7 2.3H48v352h352V350.5c0-2.1.8-4.1 2.3-5.6zm156.6-201.8L296.3 405.7l-90.4 10c-26.2 2.9-48.5-19.2-45.6-45.6l10-90.4L432.9 17.1c22.9-22.9 59.9-22.9 82.7 0l43.2 43.2c22.9 22.9 22.9 60 .1 82.8zM460.1 174L402 115.9 216.2 301.8l-7.3 65.3 65.3-7.3L460.1 174zm64.8-79.7l-43.2-43.2c-4.1-4.1-10.8-4.1-14.8 0L436 82l58.1 58.1 30.9-30.9c4-4.2 4-10.8-.1-14.9z"></path></svg><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="trash-alt" class="svg-inline--fa fa-trash-alt fa-w-14 editIcon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M268 416h24a12 12 0 0 0 12-12V188a12 12 0 0 0-12-12h-24a12 12 0 0 0-12 12v216a12 12 0 0 0 12 12zM432 80h-82.41l-34-56.7A48 48 0 0 0 274.41 0H173.59a48 48 0 0 0-41.16 23.3L98.41 80H16A16 16 0 0 0 0 96v16a16 16 0 0 0 16 16h16v336a48 48 0 0 0 48 48h288a48 48 0 0 0 48-48V128h16a16 16 0 0 0 16-16V96a16 16 0 0 0-16-16zM171.84 50.91A6 6 0 0 1 177 48h94a6 6 0 0 1 5.15 2.91L293.61 80H154.39zM368 464H80V128h288zm-212-48h24a12 12 0 0 0 12-12V188a12 12 0 0 0-12-12h-24a12 12 0 0 0-12 12v216a12 12 0 0 0 12 12z"></path></svg></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

A whole lot of code

Why is this happening? Im desesperate and have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading to 1.0.2 fixed the issue